# Number of ways to pick A objects from group X, B objects from group Y, and C objects from group Z, without repeats.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I am building an NFL survival pool app and want to find the highest probable path of surviving by picking a varying numbers of teams each week, without picking the same team twice. I want to first check the number of paths possible before analyzing the probability of each, to limit the number of paths. Lets say these are my options for 3 weeks:

Week 1 (2 picks required): (A, B, C, D, E, F)

Week 2 (1 pick required): (A, C, E, G, H, I)

Week 3 (3 picks required): (A, B, D, H, J, K, L)

I am only allowed to pick a given team once, meaning if I pick A in week 1 I can't pick them in week 2 or 3. How can I figure out the total number of ways to make 2 picks in week 1, 1 pick in week 2, and 3 picks in week 3?